# Compiling using gcc of a Cpp code which is calling a TCL script

Tags: c++, tcl

I have a cpp code in which I have included tcl.h library. I am trying to compile it using the gcc compiler. but I'm getting the following error :

```
gcc -o top.o -std=c99 top.c 
top.c:12: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
/tmp/ccDOTTZQ.o: In function `main':
top.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `Tcl_CreateInterp'
top.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Tcl_EvalFile'
top.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetVar2Ex'
top.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `Tcl_ListObjGetElements'
top.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetString'
top.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `Tcl_GetInt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Its not able to find the Cpp-tcl APIs. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: You have to link against the libraries. Something like libtcl.so

Comment: which option should I use to link them and where this object file will be available?

Comment: I don't know where the object file is. But if they are in the standard location add `-ltcl` to the g++ compilation. If they are not in the standard location add `-L/path/to/libctl.so`. **Note:** in -l option, the lib prefix and .so suffix should not be passed

Comment: I tried giving a -ltcl option. It worked. Thank you.

Comment: I also need to read locally declared variable(inside TCL script) value from tcl script  and also need to pass a value to the TCL script from my cpp code. how to do this?

Comment: That's a separate question, so you should create a new one. For the compile solution, you should add it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise this question has little value for future readers.'

Comment: Oh that's fun. The missing `-c` option is making your code do something slightly weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not linking to the Tcl library, so obviously it can't find the implementations of those functions. (In C and C++, the linking to the *implementations* of functions is a separate stage from the use of the *declarations* of those functions, which is what the header files provide.)

Except that you're *actually* calling gcc wrong. You need to use two steps, first with `-c` to *compile* the source code to an object file:

```
gcc -c -o top.o -std=c99 top.c
```

Then like this to link the result and make an executable:

```
gcc -o top.exe -std=c99 top.o -ltcl
```

With the first, you might need to additionally specify an appropriate `-I` option to locate the include files (if they're not in the standard locations). With the second, you might need to specify an appropriate `-L` option to locate the library files (`libtcl.so`). Depending on the system, you might also need to specify some version numbers (e.g., `-ltcl86` or `-ltcl8.6` instead of `-ltcl`). These are all options that depend on your build system configuration, so they're hard to predict exactly here.

Comment: In general, people build C and C++ code using a tool like `make` (or `cmake`, which I can't help with).